# aggregate of array values

Tags: sql, arrays, apache-spark, hive

Given a table on a specific day with different hex_ids I would like to aggregate the data such that the total distinct users for hex_id A is the sum of distinct users in hex_id [A, B, C]

```
+----------+-------+------+---------+
|   date_id|user_id|hex_id|  hex_map|
+----------+-------+------+---------+
|2016-11-01|    100|     A|[A, B, C]|
|2016-11-01|    300|     B|      [B]|
|2016-11-01|    400|     B|      [B]|
|2016-11-01|    100|     C|   [B, C]|
|2016-11-01|    200|     C|   [B, C]|
|2016-11-01|    300|     C|   [B, C]|
+----------+-------+------+---------+

I would like to aggregate the table on hex_id such that the value

+------+---------+---+
|hex_id|  hex_map|cnt|
+------+---------+---+
|     A|[A, B, C]|  1|
|     B|      [B]|  2|
|     C|   [B, C]|  3|
+------+---------+---+

becomes being replaced by the alphabets
+------+---------+---+
|hex_id|  hex_map|cnt|
+------+---------+---+
|     A|       6 |  1|
|     B|       2 |  2|
|     C|       5 |  3|
+------+---------+---+
```

This is run on spark sql 2.4.0 I am stumped on how to achieve this.
Where the value of 6 comes from [A+B+C]

my best attempt is

```
query="""
with cte as (select hex_id, hex_map, count(distinct user_id) cnt from tab group by hex_id, hex_map),
     subq as (select hex_id as hex, cnt as cnts, explode(hex_map) xxt from cte),
     sss (select * from subq a left join cte b  on a.xxt = b.hex_id)
     select hex, sum(cnt) from sss group by hex
"""
spark.sql(query).show()
```

Comment: Your attempted SQL looks like it's on right track. What happens?

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify the behavior of your aggregation, I decided to use `first`, but you can adapt it to your wish.

The idea is to convert the character to the `ascii` representation, you can do that through the code below:

```
val df1 = spark.sql("select hex_id, first(hex_map) as first_hex_map from test group by hex_id")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")

val df2 = spark.sql("select hex_id, transform(first_hex_map, a -> ascii(a) - 64) as aggr from df1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

val df3 = spark.sql("select hex_id, aggr, aggregate(aggr, 0, (acc, x) -> acc + x) as final from df2")
```

final result:

```
+------+---------+-----+
|hex_id|aggr     |final|
+------+---------+-----+
|A     |[1, 2, 3]|6    |
|B     |[2]      |2    |
|C     |[2, 3]   |5    |
+------+---------+-----+
```

or using `Dataset API`:

```
df.groupBy("hex_id").agg(first("hex_map").as("first_hex_map"))
  .withColumn("transformed", transform(col("first_hex_map"), a => ascii(a).minus(64)))
  .withColumn("hex_map", aggregate(col("transformed"), lit(0), (acc, x) => acc.plus(x)))
```

Good luck!

Comment: Would this work if A had 5 records? In which case the output would have to be 10.

Comment: Yes, because we are doing this on every array element, then finally aggregating it, if you think something is off, an example might help me understand better